# Inline stimulus data-action in rails erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stimulusjs

Rails 6.1
Stimulus

here is my code

index.html.erb

```
<form action="./rooms" method="get" class="text-black", data-filter-target="filter" >
      <label>
        <% if params[:creator] %>
          <input type="checkbox" name="creator" value="me" data-action="click->filter#checkout" checked >
        <% else %>
          <input type="checkbox" name="creator" value="me" data-action="click->filter#checkout">
        <% end %>
        filter something
      </label>
</form>
```

filter_controller.js

```
import { Controller } from "stimulus"
import Rails from "@rails/ujs"

export default class extends Controller {
  static targets = ["filter"]

  checkout() {
    this.filterTarget.submit()
  }
}
```

what I expect

without filter_controller.js

just click checkbox -> form submit

Answer (score 0):

add data-controller="filter" in both the input tags. and remove the data-filter-target in the div